# What sort of QA testing is related to Java MQ

Tags: automated-tests, activemq-classic, mq

What sort of testing is related to Java Message Queue? What sort of scenarios can I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic wiki on how to test message queue is 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Processing+Message+Queues+with+Java+Messaging+Service+(JMS)

In case you are trying to test a message broker ... this oracle guide should help
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/aeqas/index.html

Also a previous post talk more about Java MQ Testing in general
[Mock or simulate Message Queue (JMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970567/mock-or-simulate-message-queue-jms)